# Number of hosts in a subnet

Tags: networking, ip-address, ipv4, subnet

Does anyone know how many host bits are needed to guarantee that a subnet could have 9 usable hosts?

I was thinking about around 4, but I'm not sure. Can some shed some light on this?

Comment: Just because it has to do with a network _protocol_ doesn't mean it belongs on serverfault. If it had to do with a piece of network _equipment_, then yes.

Comment: **@John Saunders:** Addressing is definitely in the scope of *network equipment installation and maintenance*.

Answer (score 11):

Two subnet addresses (all-ones and all-zeros) can't be used to indicate a host, so with N bits you get up to `(2**N - 2)` usable hosts. So, for 9 hosts, 4 bits is correct: it would do up to 14, but 3 bits would do only 6 hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Here are networks that meet the requirement 192.168.1.0 /28

```
Mask:255.255.255.240 Host/Net - 14
Network          Broadcast
192.168.1.0      192.168.1.15
192.168.1.16     192.168.1.31
192.168.1.32     192.168.1.47
192.168.1.48     192.168.1.63
192.168.1.64     192.168.1.79
192.168.1.80     192.168.1.95
192.168.1.96     192.168.1.111
192.168.1.112    192.168.1.127
192.168.1.128    192.168.1.143
192.168.1.144    192.168.1.159
192.168.1.160    192.168.1.175
192.168.1.176    192.168.1.191
192.168.1.192    192.168.1.207
192.168.1.208    192.168.1.223
192.168.1.224    192.168.1.239
192.168.1.240    192.168.1.255
```

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate number of host bit by 2 methods:

1. We require 9 usable hosts

So converting 9 into binary we have  00001001.

Now,

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 
0    0  0  0 1 0 0 1
```

count from right to left now, till the last on bit
so into 00001001 we have  last on bit at 1
get the borrow bit till last on bit, that is 4

now for if we are calculating for class c , than the default subnet mask is
255.255.255.00000000

Now for calculation we off the bits where as for network we on the bit

so for host off 4 bits from right to left and on the rest left bits.
here 4 is the borrow bit that was calculated earlier

255.255.255.11110000

now taking only the last bit of subnet mask,

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 
1    1  1  1 0 0 0 0
```

the increment value is 16

Note: increment value is calculated as last on bit from left to right.

so we will have a network of 128+64+32+16= 240
for class 'C' we have 192.168.1.0/28 or 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.240
number of host: 192.168.1.0
192.168.1.16
this is the first network, here we have 192.168.1.0 as network IP and 192.168.1.15 as broadcast IP

so from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.14 are the usable IP or host that claculates to 14 usable host.

2nd method

we have the formula of claculating the host as 2^(n)-2
here n are off bits

from the 1st method we have number of off bit is 4

so 2^4 - 2= 16-2 = 14

hence we will get a slot of 14 usable host from which we can use 9

NOTE: The network class taken above is just an example which does not have any effect on increment bit calculation.Similarly we can calculate for class A and B